# Reading .pyth filetype in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pre-trained-model

There is pretrained model in a repository that its file type is .pyth. I searched the web to find out about this file type and which language is able to read that but I could not find anything. Since I am working with PyTorch, is it possible to read such file in PyTorch? Moreover, normally how it is possible  to read and generate that?

To be clearer, in the [repository of the TimeSformer](https://github.com/facebookresearch/TimeSformer) model, the pretrained models are of this filetype and as an example, you can find the following commands in that repository:

```
import torch
from timesformer.models.vit import TimeSformer

model = TimeSformer(img_size=224, num_classes=400, num_frames=8, attention_type='divided_space_time',  pretrained_model='/path/to/pretrained/model.pyth')

dummy_video = torch.randn(2, 3, 8, 224, 224) # (batch x channels x frames x height x width)

pred = model(dummy_video,) # (2, 400)
```

Comment: do you mean ".pt"? This is the Pytorch file format for saving models

Comment: @TheodorPeifer , no the filetype of the model weights are of this kind. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file extension can literally be anything, it doesn't change the file contents. If you run `torch.load("file.pyth")` it will load a weight dictionary. You can find this in the code in the repo you included. They save the model using this code:

```
path_to_checkpoint = get_path_to_checkpoint(path_to_job, epoch + 1)
with PathManager.open(path_to_checkpoint, "wb") as f:
    torch.save(checkpoint, f)
```

and the `get_path_to_checkpoint` function can be found [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/TimeSformer/blob/a7b3ee2560675a0b9fbae40008f504c3243e29ac/timesformer/utils/checkpoint.py#L46):

```
def get_path_to_checkpoint(path_to_job, epoch):
    """
    Get the full path to a checkpoint file.
    Args:
        path_to_job (string): the path to the folder of the current job.
        epoch (int): the number of epoch for the checkpoint.
    """
    name = "checkpoint_epoch_{:05d}.pyth".format(epoch)
    return os.path.join(get_checkpoint_dir(path_to_job), name)
```

So, they just pass a filename with an extension `.pyth` to `torch.save`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As a question, I downloaded a pytorch checkpoint file for a model from github that the file has not any extension and when I wanted to select the directory for downloading, the filetype was all files. For loading such a file as the pretrained weights of that model,  by using which filetype I should read that checkloint ( e.g. /path/to/checkpoint.???) ?

Comment: I don't know. It depends how they saved their models, have a look for `torch.save` in the code repo you have cloned and see which extension they save as.